# Multiple selections in altair

Tags: python, altair

I would like to have two interactive legends, similar to the second example in 
[this section](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/interactions.html#selection-targets-fields-and-encodings)
of the Altair docs, but without the rectangular legend.
One legend should control the color via one categorical variable ("First name"), while the second should control the marker via another categorical variable ("Last name"). While I'm able to get the aesthetics right (see below plot), the interactivity of the second legend leads to unexpected behavior.

[image: figure]

The code I used to generate the above figure is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

# Create dataframe
data = [[7, 10, 'Alex', 'Smith'],
        [12, 20, 'Bob', 'Jones'],
        [10, 30, 'Clive', 'Smith'],
        [42, 40,  'Alex', 'Johnson']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Favorite number', 'Age', 'First name', 'Last name'])

# Create selections
selection_first_name = alt.selection_multi(fields=['First name'])
selection_last_name = alt.selection_multi(fields=['Last name'])

# Create first name conditions
color_first_name = alt.condition(selection_first_name,
                                 alt.Color('First name:N', legend=None),
                                 alt.value('lightgray'))

# Create last name conditions
shape_last_name = alt.condition(selection_last_name,
                                    alt.Shape('Last name:N', legend=None),
                                    alt.value('lightgray'))

# Create interactive scatter plot
scatter = alt.Chart(df).mark_point(size=100).encode(
    x='Favorite number:Q',
    y='Age:Q',
    color=color_first_name,
    shape=shape_last_name,
    tooltip=['First name', 'Last name']
).add_selection(
    selection_first_name
).add_selection(
    selection_last_name
).add_selection(
    alt.selection_interval(bind='scales')
)

# Create interactive model name legend
legend_first_name = alt.Chart(df).mark_point(size=100).encode(
    y=alt.Y('First name:N', axis=alt.Axis(orient='right')),
    color=color_first_name
).add_selection(
    selection_first_name
)

# Create interactive model name legend
legend_last_name = alt.Chart(df).mark_point(size=100).encode(
    y=alt.Y('Last name:N', axis=alt.Axis(orient='right')),
    shape=shape_last_name
).add_selection(
    selection_last_name
)

# Combine plotting elements
chart = scatter | legend_first_name | legend_last_name
```

The resulting HTML chart is here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .vega-actions a {
        margin-right: 12px;
        color: #757575;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    .error {
        color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega@5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega-lite@3.4.0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega-embed@4"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="vis"></div>
  <script>
    (function(vegaEmbed) {
      var spec = {"config": {"view": {"width": 400, "height": 300}, "mark": {"tooltip": null}}, "hconcat": [{"mark": {"type": "point", "size": 100}, "encoding": {"color": {"condition": {"type": "nominal", "field": "First name", "legend": null, "selection": "selector001"}, "value": "lightgray"}, "shape": {"condition": {"type": "nominal", "field": "Last name", "legend": null, "selection": "selector002"}, "value": "lightgray"}, "tooltip": [{"type": "nominal", "field": "First name"}, {"type": "nominal", "field": "Last name"}], "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "Favorite number"}, "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "Age"}}, "selection": {"selector001": {"type": "multi", "fields": ["First name"]}, "selector002": {"type": "multi", "fields": ["Last name"]}, "selector003": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales"}}}, {"mark": {"type": "point", "size": 100}, "encoding": {"color": {"condition": {"type": "nominal", "field": "First name", "legend": null, "selection": "selector001"}, "value": "lightgray"}, "y": {"type": "nominal", "axis": {"orient": "right"}, "field": "First name"}}, "selection": {"selector001": {"type": "multi", "fields": ["First name"]}}}, {"mark": {"type": "point", "size": 100}, "encoding": {"shape": {"condition": {"type": "nominal", "field": "Last name", "legend": null, "selection": "selector002"}, "value": "lightgray"}, "y": {"type": "nominal", "axis": {"orient": "right"}, "field": "Last name"}}, "selection": {"selector002": {"type": "multi", "fields": ["Last name"]}}}], "data": {"name": "data-ec767a72044047bc9825da631c9465fc"}, "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.4.0.json", "datasets": {"data-ec767a72044047bc9825da631c9465fc": [{"Favorite number": 7, "Age": 10, "First name": "Alex", "Last name": "Smith"}, {"Favorite number": 12, "Age": 20, "First name": "Bob", "Last name": "Jones"}, {"Favorite number": 10, "Age": 30, "First name": "Clive", "Last name": "Smith"}, {"Favorite number": 42, "Age": 40, "First name": "Alex", "Last name": "Johnson"}]}};
      var embedOpt = {"mode": "vega-lite"};

      function showError(el, error){
          el.innerHTML = ('<div class="error" style="color:red;">'
                          + '<p>JavaScript Error: ' + error.message + '</p>'
                          + "<p>This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. "
                          + "See the javascript console for the full traceback.</p>"
                          + '</div>');
          throw error;
      }
      const el = document.getElementById('vis');
      vegaEmbed("#vis", spec, embedOpt)
        .catch(error => showError(el, error));
    })(vegaEmbed);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shape encoding has a condition that looks like this:

```
shape_last_name = alt.condition(selection_last_name,
                                    alt.Shape('Last name:N', legend=None),
                                    alt.value('lightgray'))
```

it specifies that when a point is not selected, it should have the shape named `lightgray`. `lightgray` is not a valid shape, so no points are drawn.

If you want to change the color based on the shape selection, you should put the condition in the color encoding. If you want to change the shape based on the shape legend selection, you should use a valid shape value within the condition.

I suspect what you were after was something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

# Create dataframe
data = [[7, 10, 'Alex', 'Smith'],
        [12, 20, 'Bob', 'Jones'],
        [10, 30, 'Clive', 'Smith'],
        [42, 40,  'Alex', 'Johnson']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Favorite number', 'Age', 'First name', 'Last name'])

# Create selections
selection_first_name = alt.selection_multi(fields=['First name'], empty='none')
selection_last_name = alt.selection_multi(fields=['Last name'], empty='none')

# Create interactive scatter plot
scatter = alt.Chart(df).mark_point(size=100).encode(
    x='Favorite number:Q',
    y='Age:Q',
    color=alt.condition(selection_first_name & selection_last_name,
                        alt.Color('First name:N', legend=None),
                        alt.value('lightgray') ),
    shape=alt.Shape('Last name:N', legend=None),
    tooltip=['First name', 'Last name']
).add_selection(
    alt.selection_interval(bind='scales')
)

# Create interactive model name legend
legend_first_name = alt.Chart(df).mark_point(size=100).encode(
    y=alt.Y('First name:N', axis=alt.Axis(orient='right')),
    color=alt.condition(selection_first_name,
                        alt.Color('First name:N', legend=None),
                        alt.value('lightgray') ),
).add_selection(
    selection_first_name

)

# Create interactive model name legend
legend_last_name = alt.Chart(df).mark_point(size=100).encode(
    y=alt.Y('Last name:N', axis=alt.Axis(orient='right')),
    shape=alt.Shape('Last name:N', legend=None),
    color=alt.condition(selection_last_name,
                        alt.value('black'),
                        alt.value('lightgray') ),
).add_selection(
    selection_last_name
)

# Combine plotting elements
chart = scatter | legend_first_name | legend_last_name
```

Comment: Thanks @jakevdp! This is very close to what I had in mind. There are two additional changes that I'd like to make that I'm having trouble with:
1. In the previous plot, you could click on a data point and it would change the selections. Can we change that here?
2. The odd thing about this logic is that if remove "empty=`none`" from the selections, and you select Alex, Bob, and Clive from the legend, the markers are still gray. This seems unintuitive. Any way to change this?
Happy to make separate questions for these as well

Comment: (1) Yes, if you add the selections to the scatter chart, you will be able to interact with the selections via the scatter chart. (2) That is a bug in vega-lite where logical combinations of selections don't respect the `empty="all"` starting state, and the selection is treated as empty until you interact with it.

Comment: Here's the relevant vega-lite bug for composing selections: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5553